# Can not post on a Facebook page as a admin using graph api php codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can not post on a facebook page as a admin.It gives me this error

```
Exception occured, code: 200 with message: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Although i am the admin of the page here are my permissions.I think i have the required permissions but still my code is not working

```
["permissions"]=>
    object(stdClass)#41 (1) {
      ["data"]=>
      array(5) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#42 (2) {
          ["permission"]=>
          string(12) "user_friends"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "granted"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#43 (2) {
          ["permission"]=>
          string(5) "email"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "granted"
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#44 (2) {
          ["permission"]=>
          string(12) "manage_pages"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "granted"
        }
        [3]=>
        object(stdClass)#45 (2) {
          ["permission"]=>
          string(15) "publish_actions"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "granted"
        }
        [4]=>
        object(stdClass)#46 (2) {
          ["permission"]=>
          string(14) "public_profile"
          ["status"]=>
          string(7) "granted"
        }
      }
```

Here is my code

```
if (isset($session)) {
            $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
            $session = new FacebookSession($session->getToken());


            $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me?fields=accounts{access_token,category,name,id,perms},permissions');
            $response = $request->execute();

            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
            $fb_data = array(
                'me' => $graphObject,
                'loginUrl' => $helper->getLoginUrl($facebook_default_scope),
           );
            $this->ci->session->set_userdata('fb_data', $fb_data);
            /*Facebook Post*/
                try {
                  $response = (new FacebookRequest(
                    1420447421611683 is $page_id
                    $session, 'POST', '/1420447421611683/feed', array(
                      'access_token'  => $fb_data['me']['accounts']->data[0]->access_token,
                      'link' => 'www.example.com',
                      'message' => 'Whats Up',
                    )
                  ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
                  echo "Posted with id: " . $response->getProperty('id');
                } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
                      echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
                      echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
                } 
            /*End*/
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. You're missing the permission `publish_pages` in your access token. Remember also that you should use a Page Access Token to post as the page.

Here's some documentation mentioning `publish_pages`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3